# Author page indexed, but how to deal with DC article list?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, duplicate-content, author

I create dedicated pages for content portal authors. I have good authors with high E-A-T, so I would be happy to let author pages be indexed.

Author pages contain name, photo, bio, contact data and social network links.

Until now everything is OK.

However, it seems to be usual to publish on the author's page a list of the author's articles. On this place I stumble: a list of author's articles is DC (duplicated content) - all these articles are already published in other places. The way to avoid DC would be to *noindex* this page.

So my questions are:

- Do you think, it is OK to publish an author page without an article list?
- Alternatively, do you see a method to have an article list on the indexed author page without being negatively affected by DC?

Comment: You wouldn't be publishing full articles on this bio page, right?  I'd think it would be just a list of links possibly with short excerpts. If so, that shouldn't be a big problem.  See [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)